# Adding labels to time series in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[Image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YTo0.png)
[I want to add labels of the state names (col names at the end of each line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdCJN.png)

Code for ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

NewPlot <- ggplot(pf, aes(x = newDate)) +
geom_line(aes(y=WY), color = "red") +
geom_line(aes(y=ND), color = "red") +
geom_line(aes(y=OK), color = "red") +
geom_line(aes(y=ID), color = "red") +
geom_line(aes(y=WV), color = "red") +
geom_line(aes(y=MA), color = "blue") +
geom_line(aes(y=HI), color = "blue") +
geom_line(aes(y=VT), color = "blue") +
geom_line(aes(y=MD), color = "blue") +
geom_line(aes(y=CA), color = "blue") +
labs(title = "Time Series for Total Number of COVID-19 Doses Administered (per 100k) vs. U.S States") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
xlab("Date (Time-Series)") +
ylab("Total Number of COVID-19 Doses Adminstered (per 100k)")
```

I tried using geom_labels, geom_text, annotation, but the error fortify() keep popping up. I just want one label at the end of each line.

Comment: Please make this question reproducible. NEVER add images of data.frames, and rather include code for the data. The gold standard is to include the output of `dput(data.frame.name)` or `dput(head(data.frame.name, 20))` as a code block

Comment: not directly related to the question

Answer (score 1):

To label the end of each line, you can create a separate dataframe with only those points. Without any reproducible data sample, I first generate some toy data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(dates = seq(ymd('2022-01-01'), ymd('2022-12-31'), by = '1 month'),
                 WY = sample(100000:150000, 12),
                 MA = sample(100000:150000, 12),
                 NM = sample(100000:150000, 12))
glimpse(df)
#> Rows: 12
#> Columns: 4
#> $ dates <date> 2022-01-01, 2022-02-01, 2022-03-01, 2022-04-01, 2022-05-01, 202…
#> $ WY    <int> 102985, 129924, 129709, 137528, 102756, 145403, 146434, 138937, …
#> $ MA    <int> 127167, 124172, 109096, 130537, 128980, 107988, 113535, 149368, …
#> $ NM    <int> 128824, 141236, 100040, 114425, 140158, 107283, 143781, 128501, …
```

Now we can filter for the ends of the lines, which is just the last date in the dataset. We also can pivot this data to a longer form, which is a good practice when working with `ggplot2`.

```r
end_labels <- df %>%
  filter(dates == max(dates)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-dates, names_to = 'state', values_to = 'pop')
```

Finally, we pivot the full data frame as above, and create the plot. I am using the `ggrepel` package for the labels, but you could substitute `geom_label`.

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-dates, names_to = 'state', values_to = 'pop') %>%
  ggplot(aes(dates, pop, color = state)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggrepel::geom_label_repel(data = end_labels, aes(label = state)) +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]